# Is MERGE statement is a good option to use when we are just updating a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

I know `MERGE` is used if we have to combine multiple operations`(INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE)`. But in my case, I have a `procedure` which is using `MERGE` statement to update few `columns` in a `table`. But sometimes it takes a lot of time to run which is not expected because data is not that big. So is it because of MERGE and is it okay to use `merge` or should I change it to `UPDATE` statement?

Comment: compare between the two approaches , and choose the best of them via access plan, show statistics .. so on.

Comment: If your intention is just to update, you should stick to an `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `UPDATE`. It is more tried and tested and has fewer bugs and can have better execution plans. It is also clearer to see the intent when reading the source code.

The semantics are not always the same however.

If the table source has multiple rows that could map to a target row then `MERGE` will raise an error and `UPDATE` will non deterministically select one of the possible options.

If this semantic is important to you (you want to assert that there is only one match and error if this is violated) then you might want to stick with `MERGE`.